# react native search result too large and need pagination

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, infinite-scroll

i am new to this react native and i am require to develop a simple app to search something from given api. Given api does not have pages but count of results and sometimes the results  that comes out is large

this case, my search result is loading while displaying some of the result from the api. I found out this to be very bad design for myself and i wanted to do something like load only 10 result first and when scroll until end will load another 10 results and keep on going with 10 results. I think this is call infinite scrolling?

during my search in google, i see alot of example but i am not sure how to implement this on my side instead. This is my search code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Alert, Dimensions, Platform, View,TouchableOpacity,TouchableHighlight,FlatList  } from 'react-native'
import { Button,Header, Icon, Input, Item, Left, Right, Text,Thumbnail } from 'native-base'
import { ListItem, Avatar } from 'react-native-elements'


const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window')
class Search extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      searchResult: [],
    };
  }

   static navigationOptions = {
   title: "Search Results",
             headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#4050B5',
            },
            headerTintColor: '#fff',
            headerTitleStyle: {
              fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
  };

  getSearchResult(searchURL){
    console.log("Search URL is => "+searchURL);
    return fetch(searchURL)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({searchResult:responseJson.result});
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }

  configureSearchURL(props){
    const { navigation } = props;
    let selectedTitles = navigation.getParam('selectedTitles');
    let searchKeyword = navigation.getParam('searchKeyword');
    console.log("selectTitles => "+selectedTitles);
    console.log("searchKeyword => "+searchKeyword);
    let searchURL = 'https://imas-go.com/test_item_search.php?';
    let titleParameter = "";

    if(selectedTitles != null || selectedTitles != ""){
       for (let i=0;i<selectedTitles.length;i++){
        if(i==0){
          titleParameter+="vers[]="+selectedTitles[i];
        } else {
          titleParameter+="&vers[]="+selectedTitles[i];
        }
      }
      searchURL+=titleParameter;
    }

    if(searchKeyword.trim().length > 0){
      searchURL+="&name="+searchKeyword;
    }
    console.log("final search url => "+searchURL);
    this.getSearchResult(searchURL);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
   this.configureSearchURL(this.props);
  }

  keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.sno+item.name;

renderItem = ({ item }) => (
 <ListItem
      title= {item.name}
      subtitle={
        <View style={styles.subtitleView}>
          <Text style={styles.ratingText}>Ver: {item.ver}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.ratingText}>Price: {item.price}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.ratingText}>Stock: {item.stock}</Text>
        </View>
      }
     avatar={<Avatar
                large
                medium
                source={{uri: `https://imas-go.com/card_image/ws/front/${item.ver}/${item.cid}.jpg`}}
                onPress={() => console.log("Works!")}
              />}
    />
)   
  render() {

      return(
        <FlatList
      keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
      data={this.state.searchResult}
      renderItem={this.renderItem}
    />

        );
  }
}

styles = StyleSheet.create({
  subtitleView: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingTop: 5
  },
  ratingText: {
    paddingLeft: 10,
    color: 'grey'
  }
})

export default Search;
```

i have a page that searches with keywords and category and redirect to this search.js page and form the parameter for the api search url. Hope someone can help me in implement this

Answer (score 0):

Try using flatlist, That will take a few set of data and lazy loads the rest.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new state called "currentView" which refers to this.currentView() like this:

```
this.state = {
  currentView: this.currentView(),
  currentPagination: []
}
```

And then you simply define a for loop like this:

```
currentView() {
 let pagination = 10; // Set how many you want to show each time
 let list = []; // The list you will render
 let currentPagination = this.state.currentPagination.length

 for (let i = 0; i < pagination; i++) {
     let arr = this.state.searchresults.slice(currentPagination)
     list.push(arr[i]);
 };
 this.setState({currentPagination: list})

 return list;
}
```

To make it load when you scroll you'll need to set something up in `componentDidUpdate()`, something like this:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  let windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
  let scrollState = window.scrollY;
  let offset = 100; // If you want to start the load earlier than the bottom

  if (scrollState > windowHeight - offset) {
    this.currentView();
  }
}
```

Comment: how do i implement this into my current render view? once i press search button from previous page, i need to show something 1st?  under my flatlist  data={this.state.searchResult}, the data should be getting from where? this.currentView(); ? i tried this and have no result came out

Comment: You'd need to switch in your flatList to data={this.state.currentPagination} otherwise it will show all results at all times

Comment: following this i get undefined is not an object for this.state.currentPagination error

Comment: Where are you getting the error? Can you show an example of how this.state.searchResults look like?

Comment: just getting undefined is not an object for this.state.currentPagination

here is my constructor
 constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      searchResult: [],
      currentView: this.currentView(),
      currentPagination: []
    };
  }

from the api, the search result data is something like this
{"status":1,"result_count":2,"result":[{"ver":"dc","cid":"10060","stock":"2","price":"200","sp_price":"0","sno":"DC\/W01-056","name":"譛晏� 髻ｳ螟｢"},{"ver":"dc","cid":"10061","stock":"8","price":"30","sp_price":"0","sno":"DC\/W01-056R","name":"譛晏� 髻ｳ螟｢"}]}

Comment: i think the error is coming from here 
let currentPagination = this.state.currentPagination.length

or this    currentView: this.currentView() in state constructor

Comment: Try setting the flatlist data to this.state.currentView

Comment: Can you update your code with what you've done and send here? Maybe use a site like pastebin or similar. I tested the code and I don't understand how you're getting undefined.

Comment: @user1897151 You still need help with it? I found a solution but the comments are getting too long here. Would you be able to check if it works in the chat?